# More general title or more specific title?

Tags: discussion, questions

I recently posted this question:

[How to share internet among 2 android devices?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4117/how-to-share-internet-among-2-android-devices)

And through the miracle of Android Enthusiasts, came up with the answers needed.  However, the question started as, essentially "connect 2 android devices" but the answers wound up depending on the specific devices (for example, the config file for the tablet may very well be tablet-specific;  I know that other android devices require additional edits to config that the tablet did not).  Should I edit the question to reflect more exactly the answers, something like "How To Connect my Archos Gentouch 78 tablet to my G1's internet connection" or leave it in its more general format?

Comment: I think it answers both.  Usually one just roots and uses a wifi sharing app to enable other devices to connect to the internet via it, but in your case you had to enable adhoc wifi first.  I'm fine with leaving it as it is.

Answer (score 5):

Your title is fine. The text of the question gets to the heart of the matter and the specific advice may well apply to other devices. Being too specific would likely keep people from visiting the question. I think you struck a good balance.

On the other hand, titles like "I need help!" are absolutely horrendous.

Comment: I second this line of thinking.

Answer (score 0):

I say edit the title to suit the answers (esp the accepted one).
It helps the user with the same specific problem as you, it prevents people from being disappointed when reading the title and found that the solutions does not apply to his problem.

I think it's also better search-engine wise.